# When I was turning on Mariadb in XAMPP, I encountered an error

Tags: mariadb

The XAMPP was working for me until yesterday, but today this suddenly happened:

[image]

I searched on the internet about this issue and it said that I should replace the backup folder with data. But my databases are not in the backup folder.

I have these error in Mariadb log:

[image]

I run into this problem every now and then and have to delete XAMPP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).